# Unable to fetch data from firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, firebase-admin

I am working on a dialogflow agent and using fulfillment to fetch data from the firestore.
I have a firestore collection called **Users** which has name and location fields. But am getting the error which causes the fetching of data to fail.

> Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT.
>   Initializing firebase-admin may fail

The fulfillment code for the agent is as follows

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Card, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
 console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
 console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));


var name='';
var location='';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

 function getUserDetails(agent)
 {
     name= agent.parameters.name;
     location=agent.parameters.location;
     console.log("buyer name is " + name);
     db.collection("Users").doc("101").set({
    name: name,
    location:location});
    agent.add(`User has been inserted`);   
 }

 intentMap.set('Buy Car', getUserDetails);
 agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This form of initialization for the Firebase Admin SDK is deprecated:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

You should initialize like this instead:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

Comment: Function got executed but the document is not inserted into the firestore collection.

Comment: OK, it sounds like you now have a different problem that requires a new question to ask.